# Serilog Exceptionless Sink in .NET Core 1.1

Tags: serilog, asp.net-core-1.1, exceptionless

How can the Serilog Exceptionless Sink be used with .NET Core 1.1?

The [Serilog.Sinks.Exceptionless README](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-exceptionless/blob/master/README.md) isn't clear and doesn't work for .NET Core 1.1 where I have put the configuration in the appsettings.json file.

```json
{
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": ["Serilog.Sinks.Literate"],
    "MinimumLevel": ["Debug"],
    "WriteTo": [{
      "Name": "LiterateConsole"
    }],
    "Enrich": ["FromLogContext"],
    "Properties": {
      "Application": "MyAppServer"
    }
  }
}
```

Program.cs

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(config)
            .CreateLogger();
    }
}
```

I obviously need to set up the API key somewhere, too.

Can anyone provide a clear description of how this can be configured, please?

Comment: I work on the project and manage the sink. I'm curious how the serilog sink is working for you?

Comment: The sink worked fine in the prototype but I'm no longer on that project, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JSON you can add additional sinks to the `"WriteTo"` list and add arguments like `apiKey` in the `"Args"` block:

```
{
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": ["Serilog.Sinks.Literate"],
    "MinimumLevel": ["Debug"],
    "WriteTo": [{
      "Name": "LiterateConsole"
    }, {
      "Name": "Exceptionless",
      "Args": { apiKey: "12345" }
    }],
    "Enrich": ["FromLogContext"],
    "Properties": {
      "Application": "MyAppServer"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's

```cs
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.Exceptionless(
        apiKey: "yourApiKey", 
        additionalOperation: b => b.AddTags("ASP.NET Core Example Logger"))
    .CreateLogger();
```